# moving files from one drive to another using cmd

Tags: windows

I want to move all the .zip files from several directories and sub directories on one drive to one folder on another drive.

Result; one folder containing all the .zip files

Can you tell me the exact syntex to use, in other words, what exactly would I type into my CMD prompt, I want to move all the zip files from one external drive to another. 
example:

f:\Karaoke Drive *.zip (from all folders and sub folders to
e:\ Karaoke Drive (no sub folders, all the zips)

Comment: Have you considered what should happen if several zip files have the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Try xcopy. You can get the command-line syntax like this:

```
xcopy /?
```